# freeware for hiding Site template folders

Tags: explorer

I am new to SharePoint and I would like to use the Microsoft explorer for copying files to SharePoint. Although using SharePoint workstation is considered to be a best practice, I would like that my organization can stick to the old file explorer. Is there a tool or a automated script that allows me to hide old as well as new created folders(so all SharePoint related stuff, not the Document Libraries).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking to keep using Explorer View (which is an option and is enabled by default) or are you looking for a way to change the SharePoint Web Interface to make it look more like explorer?  Also, what version and edition is this for (i.e. 2007 Enterprise, 2010 Foundation...)

Comment: I am using 2010 foundation and I am aware about the explorer option enabled by default. I would like to use the explorer option but add it as a network drive. However, when doing so all internal SharePoint folders are displayed as well. I would like to just view SharePoint library folders and SharePoint lists and hide teh rest.